# Firebase service worker installed but not activated

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

From the Concole I see that my ServiceWorker is installed but I guess that I need to get it activated to receive messages from Firebase.

[image]

This is how I call it:

navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js');

I use curl to send a message and it seems to be working:
[image]

I have investigated further. It seems that the service worker did not execute as expected. Due to that I get an error when using the two intitial importScripts according to the code below I removed them and then the worker was registered but not started/executed. I get this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: 
Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': 
The script at 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.4.0/firebase-app-compat.js' failed to load.
at https://"MYSERVER".org:/firebase-messaging-sw.js:4:1

    
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.4.0/firebase-app-compat.js")
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.4.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js")
```

By putting the files on my own server I was able to continue, but still no messages yet.

I notice that the Firebase service worker is still in state "installed" but I have an "old" that is active. How can I make sure I only have one?

[image]

Comment: Finally I got it to work. One remaining problem was in the firebase-messaging-sw.js file, that did no compile.

Furthermore, I got it to work omn iOS when I added an user action to ask for permission to send notifications.

Answer (score 0):

This code did work for me. Initializing by

```
<script src="/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
<script src="/firebase-messaging-compat.js"></script>

//Firebase Push  Notifications
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "bsharp-XXX-app1.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "bsharp-XXX_123123123",
    storageBucket: "bsharp-XXX-123123123.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "123123123123",
    appId: "12312312312312312312312312",
    measurementId: "XXXXXXX"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js").then(swReg2 => {
    console.log("Firebase Worker is registered", swReg2);
})

// Call this when for example the user pushes a button. 
// Need to be a user action to get it running. Especially on iOS.
function request_acceptance_for_getting_push_notificaitons(){
    Notification
        .requestPermission()
        .then(() => {
             message("Notifications allowed");
             return messaging.getToken();
    })
    .then(token => {
        console.log( "Token Is : " + token) ; // Store in DB?
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("No permission to send push", err);
    });
  
}
  
messaging.onMessage(payload => {
    console.log("Message received. ");
    const { title, body, ...options } = payload.notification;
    console.log(title);
    console.log(body);
});
```

And then this is the firebase-messaging-sw.js code

```
importScripts("/firebase-app-compat.js")
importScripts("/firebase-messaging-compat.js")



firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "bsharp-XXX-app1.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "bsharp-XXX_123123123",
    storageBucket: "bsharp-XXX-123123123.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "123123123123",
    appId: "12312312312312312312312312",
    measurementId: "XXXXXXX"
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
    console.log(
    '[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ',
    payload
    );
});
```